# Removing item from Java List in Android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I'm having trouble with the following code.

I am getting the  the index of item and using it. Now I want to remove it's position from the list so that it  doesn't get the same position again, but when I call the method below the app crashes, and when I delete the line `myList.remove(randomIndex);`it runs good. 
Is something wrong with this line?

```
public void showtime() {

     Random rand = new Random();
     randomIndex = rand.nextInt(myList.size());

     randomName = myList.get(randomIndex);
     txtView.setText(randomName);

     if (randomIndex==1)) {
         imgLabel.setImageResource(R.drawable.Label1);
     }
     if (randomIndex==2)) {
         imgLabel.setImageResource(R.drawable.Label2);
     }
     if (randomIndex==3)) {
         imgLabel.setImageResource(R.drawable.Label3);
     }

     myList.remove(randomIndex);
  }
```

Comment: Paste your error log pls...

Comment: That's hard to tell without more information but I'd suspect the list's size is being cached somewhere in your code and the app tries to access the last element which isn't at that position anymore (aka IndexOutOfBoundsException).

Comment: Your code doesnt even compile like that: (randomIndex==3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are removing the item from list so make sure it shouldn't be **List** it must be **ArrayList**
Please try this....

Comment: What made you think he is not using `ArrayList`?

Comment: He is not mention it, I told this because once I have also faced the same problem...

Comment: This could've been posted as a comment, its not a direct answer to what the problem is, but rather a inaccurate assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that:

1- myList is an ArrayList;

2- When this method is called, myList has almost an element

Each of your if statements has a syntax error. They have an extra `)`

```
if (randomIndex==1) {
     imgLabel.setImageResource(R.drawable.Label1);
 }
 if (randomIndex==2) {
     imgLabel.setImageResource(R.drawable.Label2);
 }
 if (randomIndex==3) {
     imgLabel.setImageResource(R.drawable.Label3);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

it should be

```
    randomIndex = rand.nextInt(myList.size());
```

Comment: From [Java Random API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-): `Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.` This `-1` is wrong!!

Answer (score -1):

You can check that the generated index is within the list bounds and avoid the crash like this

```
randomIndex = rand.nextInt(myList.size()-1);

if(randomIndex <= myList.size()-1){
 myList.remove(randomIndex)
};
```

Comment: From [Java Random API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-): `Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.` This `-1` is wrong!!